# Get latest post from a specific author - genesis wordpress

Tags: wordpress, author, genesis, custom-code

I need to show the latest post by a specific author. For example, if 'test' author had two posts, one published on 1st January and the other on the 2nd January, I only want to show the 2nd Jan post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the WP_Query ordered by date and search for the specific author requested by passing it as an arg.

```
$args = [
     'author'         => $author_id,
     'orbderby'       => 'post_date',
     'order'          => 'DESC',
     'posts_per_page' => 1,
 ];
 $latestPost = new WP_Query[$args]
```

And you don't even need to loop through it you could access it's field by just referencing it. `$postContent = $latestPost->posts`

Comment: You could also probably achieve such result using the `get_posts()`